# Can I measure "CPU time" in a multithreaded app?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a multithreaded application which performs assorted slow (> 500ms) tasks on separate threads. I would like to be able to measure the "[CPU time](http://service.futurequest.net/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/407)" taken for each task. I would prefer to be able to measure CPU time directly in code rather than via some third party utility or profiler. Is there some CPU-time equivalent of System.currentTimeMillis()?

Comment: How about Android Development Tools?

Comment: @Ordous: I can't see anything there that answers my question - but maybe I haven't looked hard enough - could you give me a hint?

Comment: [Systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html) gives an overview of your process vs entire system, *including CPU scheduler and particular threads*